# Create MemberExpression from a navigation property selector string, C#?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

We have the following entities :

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Serial { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public Section Section { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public int Serial { get; set; }
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public SupperSection SupperSection { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> Sections { get; set; }
}
```

We wanna create a `MemberExpression` from the following string:

```
Employee.Section.SectionName
```

We do it as follows:

```
// selectorString = Section.SectionName
// we wanna create     entity => entity.Section.SectionName
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");    
MemberExpression result = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, selectorString); // Exception
```

but it throws the following exception :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
> System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Property 'System.String SectionName' is not defined for type 'DtoContainer.Employee'

How can we do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create object instance and build expression tree like this:

```
Employee employee = new Employee()
{
    Section = new Section() { SectionName = "test" }
};
MemberExpression sectionMember = Expression.Property(ConstantExpression.Constant(employee), "Section");
MemberExpression sectionNameMember = Expression.Property(sectionMember, "SectionName");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectorString = "Employee.Section.SectionName";
var properties = selectorString.Split(".");
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, properties[0]);

//You can add like this 
property = properties.Skip(1).Aggregate(property, (current, propertyName) => Expression.Property(current, propertyName));

//or you use a shorter version by passing as a method group
property = properties.Skip(1).Aggregate(property, Expression.Property);


var expression = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity), property.Type), property, parameter);
```